# Using dplyr mutate with conditions based on multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

Without NAs, the following code would work as intended: if the first row has any 2's in it, the new variable takes a value of 2; if not, I want to check if any of the values are 1; if not, check if any are 0; if not, then all must be NA.

Once I add NAs into the data frame, it no longer works and I can't seem to figure out why:

```
V1 <- c(NA,1,2,0,0)
V2 <- c(0,0,2,1,1)
V3 <- c(NA,0,2,1,0)

V <- cbind(V1,V2,V3)

V <- mutate(V,V4 = ifelse(V1 == 2|V2==2|V3==2, 2, 
ifelse(V1==1|V2==1|V3==1, 1, ifelse(V1==0|V2==0|V3==0,0,NA))))
```

Intended output:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1 NA  0 NA  0
2  1  0  0  1
3  2  2  2  2
4  0  1  1  1
5  0  1  0  1
```

Actual output:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1 NA  0 NA NA
2  1  0  0  1
3  2  2  2  2
4  0  1  1  1
5  0  1  0  1
```

Comment: At least for the sample data, you could just use `pmax`: `V %>% as_data_frame() %>% mutate(V4 = pmax(V1, V2, V3, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: Or for a bounded version of `pmax`, using arrays, `cbind(V, V4 = max.col(apply(outer(V, 0:2, \`==\`), c(1, 3), any, na.rm = TRUE), ties.method = 'last') - 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works as intended if you do:

```
mutate(V, V4 = case_when(
  V1 == 2 | V2 == 2 | V3 == 2 ~ 2,
  V1 == 1 | V2 == 1 | V3 == 1 ~ 1,
  V1 == 0 | V2 == 0 | V3 == 0 ~ 0
))
```

Also, you should use one of `data.frame()`, `data_frame()` or `tibble()` instead of `cbind()` to make the V object more compliant to dplyr functions, which expect a data frame instead of a matrix (which is what gets produced by `cbind()`.

Comment: Can you explain why the nested ifelse approach works when there are no NAs, but fails to work when there are NAs in the dataframe? Ifelse also works fine when the condition is based on only 1 column, even if there are NAs. Sorry I forgot to add as.data.frame in the code! I had used it to get the output

Comment: It's more concise to flip it and use `%in%`, e.g. `V %>% as_data_frame() %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(V4 = case_when(2 %in% c(V1, V2, V3) ~ 2, 1 %in% c(V1, V2, V3) ~ 1, 0 %in% c(V1, V2, V3) ~ 0))`

Comment: @alistaire yes, although `rowwise()` makes the computation slower.

Comment: You could vectorize with `rowSums`, e.g. `V %>% as_data_frame() %>% 
    mutate(V4 = case_when(rowSums(. == 2, na.rm = TRUE) > 0 ~ 2, 
                          rowSums(. == 1, na.rm = TRUE) > 0 ~ 1, 
                          rowSums(. == 0, na.rm = TRUE) > 0 ~ 0))`, but it's not prettier.

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution following @alistaire using **across** and **contains** from the **dplyr** package would be:

```
V %>% 
   as_data_frame() %>% 
   rowwise() %>% 
   mutate(V4 = case_when(2 %in% across(contains("V")) ~ 2, 
                         1 %in% across(contains("V")) ~ 1, 
                         0 %in% across(contains("V")) ~ 0))
```